# How to handle missing date data?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, feature-engineering, kaggle

I have a column named `GarageYrBlt` which just lists the year the garage of that house was built.  I have one `nan` value for this column.  Does it make sense to fill it with the columns median (This was a common approach for the missing age values in the Titanic competition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're working with the Ames house price dataset - one of Kaggle's introductory competitions.

Replacing the missing values with the dataset mean / median is very general.

I believe you have a variable which describes which neighbourhood the house is in. A more focussed approach would be to replace that missing value in `GarageYrBlt` with the mean / median for that *neighbourhood* (subject to additional sensibility checks like the garage not being built before the house).

Comment: Actually its Boston

Comment: And yea I do have a column like that but can you break down your approach a little more?

Comment: It assumes that houses in the same neighbourhood have similar characteristics - e.g. built around the same time, of similar construction, similar sized plots of land, etc. So my suggestion would be that if your missing data point is from a house in neighbourhood A, replace the missing value with a statistic calculated using other houses in neighbourhood A. You don't have to use the neighbourhood - you could instead use _year of construction_, _type of house_, etc.

Comment: The sense check was just to make sure that the statistic calculated using a broader dataset makes sense in a narrow application. E.g. I think garages are generally built at the same time (or after) a house is built, so it would make sense that the statistic you calculate to replace your missing value doesn't imply that the garage was built _before_ the house.

Comment: In the Titanic competition, I filled the age data with the mean of its column, relative to the sex so all female passengers with missing age got the mean age of all female passengers.  Is this the idea you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's the a different application but is based on the same idea.

Comment: I tried to do `train['GarageYrBlt'] = train['GarageYrBlt'].fillna(train.groupby('YearBuilt')['GarageYrBlt'].transform("median"), inplace=True)` but now all of my values appear as `None`

Comment: Maybe: `train['GarageYrBlt'] = train.groupby('YearBuilt')['GarageYrBlt'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median(),inplace=True))`

Comment: `transform` broadcasts a scalar value back to the group, so each row in the grouping has the same value.

Comment: Same thing.  I still get `NaN` for the entire column of `GarageYrBlt`

Comment: Maybe try without the `inplace = True`

Comment: Okay so now I'm able to see everything but the original `NaN` value is still intact.

Comment: Third time lucky... I think I may have misunderstood the `transform` method before. Try `train['GarageYrBlt'] = train.groupby('YearBuilt')['GarageYrBlt'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())`. If that doesn't work, I would recommend searching Stack Overflow.